# Netcat interaction issue

Tags: netcat

I am following a tutorial where two ports (45678 & 45679) are specified in an Ubuntu Docker container. The container to used to listen to input on 45678 and route them to 45679.

Then the video show using the the following command to listing for input on a new container/termainal:

```
nc 192.168.99.100 45678
```

The same command on a third terminal is the listener when the input is printed:

```
nc 192.168.99.100 45679
```

The trouble is the video show both terminals waiting for input and to print the received input - which proves tutors point.

In my case, the terminals return immediately without waiting for any thing.

Comment: usually one of the `nc` should have the `-l` flag somewhere to listen, unless the docker foo is somehow doing that somewhere